# problems installing Zeoslib 6.6.6-stable on BDS C++ builder 2006

Tags: c++, delphi, builder, zeos

I'm having problems installing ZEOSLib 6.6.6-stable in BDS C++ Builder 2006.
I only have C++Builder installed, no Delphi, but I can see the `dcc32.exe` file in the `bds/4.0/bin/` folder.

When I try to compile the packages with the Delphi compiler from the command line, as suggested in [this post](http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?t=2507), using `dcc32.exe zeosdbo.bdsgroup -JPHNE`, I receive several error messages (see below) and the compilation stops.

I've also tried opening the `builder6/zeosdbo.bpg` file in the IDE and it updates the project files to version 10 and generates a set of `.bdsgroup` files, but when trying to build the project files a `file not found Zclasses.dcu` error message apears.

Can you please provide any further help on this problems?

Messages received when trying to compile the packages with the Delphi command-line compiler:

> C:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(1) Error: E2029 Declaration expected but '<' found
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(1) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>   c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(1) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(5) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(5) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(6) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(6) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(7) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(8) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(12) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(12) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(13) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(13) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(14) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(14) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(15) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(15) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(16) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(16) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(17) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(17) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(18) Error: E2038 Illegal character in input file: '"' (#$22)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(23)
>
> c:\ZEOSDBO\packages\DELPHI10\ZeosDbo.bdsgroup(24) Error: E2029 '.' expected but end of file found

Comment: What are tthe actual errors you get on the command line?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Remy, I edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had found no alternative but to install Delphi10 builder and compile using the linker option "generate all C++ files", not without working around the $endif at zcomponent.dpk and after adding to the path the source folder where all the missing *.dcu were requested. 
After that C++ nor Delphi10 builders showed the toolbars but apparently the packages were installed correctly. 
Kind regards. Patowski